# How to avoid flicker when rendering with SurfaceView and OpenGL while change device orientation?

Tags: android, camera, opengl-es, rotation, surfaceview

The precondition is we have to let Activity rotate follow the system orientation, so i add following code to the AndroidManifest.xml：

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode"`

`android:screenOrientation="sensor"`

And set the rotationAnimation to ROTATION_ANIMATION_SEAMLESS.

`WindowManager.LayoutParams windowAttributes = getWindow().getAttributes();  windowAttributes.rotationAnimation = WindowManager.LayoutParams.ROTATION_ANIMATION_SEAMLESS;  getWindow().setAttributes(windowAttributes);`

I reset the correct glViewport, projection matrix and model matrix in surfaceChanged()，the proplem is that serveral frames looks weired while change the device orientation, but after rotation is complete, all frames look good.
This image shows what's going on:
[image]

It tried to reset viewport and matrix while onConfigurationChanged() is invoked, but it doesn't work.
I want the frames look seamless while change the device orientation, just as the Pixels' camera APP did.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: it's not possibile to avoid this completly.

You could let the SurfaceView invisible while rotation is not completed, but the Surface cannot renders not-yet-existent pixels for fill the new space that is created when the "landscape mode" is just started: Surface/View should adapts itself and it takes few milliseconds which are few frames as you reported (more the Device is slow/cheap and more frames are affected by this behavious/issue) expecially for the Camera to get new pixels from a different orientation.